# Updating python script from a git repo

Tags: python, github

I want to automatically update my project when ever I make a new commit to my github repo. Lets say I make a change on this computer. I want any other device to look for changes in the repo and update it automatically. This would be made in python. Anyone have any ideas on how I would go about that?

Comment: you need something to poll for SCM changes

Comment: not sure but maybe https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/ can help